# Find the right-cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Take $G=S_3$ and $H=<(1,2)>$. The partition of $S_3$ by the right cosets of $H$ is going to be a set of three subsets of $S_3$ each of size 2. Give each of these three sets, as sets of permutations described as products of cycles.

Here's my work. Since $S_3 = {(1),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)}$, we have the three right cosets of $H$ with size $2$, $(12)(12)=(12),(12)(13)=(132),(12)(23)=(123)$. Am I doing right?

Comment: we have (12)(12)=1

Answer (score 1):

A coset is a whole *set* of elements, as the question states. You have given three elements.

Keep in mind that $H = \langle (1, 2) \rangle$ is the set $\{e, (1, 2)\}$. In order to find a particular coset, for example $H(1, 3)$, you need to multiply each of the elements of $H$ by $(1, 3)$:

$$H(1, 3) = \{(1, 3)e, (1, 3)(1, 2)\} = \{(1, 3), (132)\}$$

(Minor note: $(1, 2)(1, 2) = e$, not $(1, 2)$).